# Just my Comments deleted

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if there's some log that will tell someone how or why my comments below this [Answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/54272/18367) were deleted.

Coming back to the question today, the comment thread seems to have been pruned, but I can see replies to my comments that quote what I said but my original comments seem to have been removed selectively from the record.

It's not that I mind really, the comment chain had wandered a bit far from the purpose of comments and if they were all gone that one be understandable, but seeing as it appears to be just the points I made that have gone it feels targeted and I'd like to know why if possible.

Comment: Whether any comments had any merit, even if temporary, or not: Alas, you most probably will get the standard reply: "comments are not meant for…/can be deleted at any time…". Which I by now feel a bit like *gaslighting users* (didn't I write sth here?) among other things. they are still there, mods and staff can read them etc. We should get access to our deleted comments etc. But that needs to go as a feature request to MetaSE. Here, most replies will defend the status quo as 'works as broken by design – deal with it'. (Note that *I'm a fan* of pruning & deleting comments!)

Answer (score 5):

It wasn't just Jontia's comment which got deleted. I deleted a total of 20 comments below that answer, of which only one was from Jontia.

The comments I deleted were mostly a debate between two users which escalated into a petty verbal slapfight. My usual modus operandi in that case is to delete the whole comment chain which escalated. Why not just the posts which clearly crossed the line? Because I made the experience that when you only remove the offending posts, then someone (either the participants or others) will respond to the remaining comments with similarly offending posts. The only way to get such an inflammatory comment thread to die down is either to hand out suspensions to everyone or to remove the whole chain up to the original post which provoked the debate.

Jontia's comment was a direct response to one of the participants in that fight and didn't make much sense anymore without that context. So I deleted it too. If anyone wants to know, this was the comment by Jontia:

> @**[redacted]** " Per Google, the number of new cases in Texas has dropped for five straight days as of June 30" Two of those days are the weekend, and as can be seen from every graph on google, data collection over the weekend means a drop on those days and a spike early in the week, so the 7 day average is better measure, as Texas' google data now has a new peak at nearly 7K cases for the 30th June.

Comment: okay dokey I must have missed it all kick off. And misremembered saying more. That's the trouble with deleted comments, I can't see them anywhere to remember what I wrote.